# Geolocation error on Wordpress map website

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress website (www.citysportshanghai.com) includes a geolocation map for different businesses in my city.  Recently, the map disappeared completely and was replaced by the following text:

> Error while handling requests or too many requests..... Please update awr_2197.js library for critical bug fixes.
>   Team Juzaans

This is a strange occurrence, as I haven't made any major changes on the site in a long time. I doubt my website was receiving too many requests.  I don't know where to find this javascript file and I don't know who or what "Team Juzaans" is. Google search, Wordpress forum and asking the developer of the website hasn't helped at all so if anyone on here has some tips I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem with your site is the url, despite your domain has a valid SSL certificate installed, your site is not using it by default.

Go to your wordpress admin panel -> general Settings 
and change both **Wordpress (URL)** and **site (URL)**
from http://www.citysportshanghai.com to **https://www.citysportshanghai.com**
[image: WP admin panel]

Second problem, even if you manually type https://www.citysportshanghai.com in the browser, your site is passing mixed conent, in order to get geolocation, all the content must be served over HTTPS.

you can force https by editing your .htaccess file but first make a BACKUP.
Again it is highly recommended to make a BACKUP before editing your .htaccess file

once you have a BACKUP of your .htacces file paste this code before the line that says **# BEGIN WordPress**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# BEGIN Wordpress
```

This will rewrite any insecure request to https://www.citysportshanghai.com
but if you cant acces your admin panel or you get a white screen of death then you will have to upload your .htaccess BACKUP file and debug you site rewriting files individually

once you finish with your .htaccess go to your site and check the console all of this errors should be gone **press F12 on Firefox or chrome**
[image: browser console]

if the problem persist well... **Please update awr_2197.js library** (pretty much update all your plugins)

Comment: Thank you for responding! I was able to visualize the map again by disabling a plugin, and reactivating the others.  However, now I'm trying to fix the geolocation and search function which are not working at all.  I added 's' to the URLs, but can you explain how to edit the .htaccess file ?

Comment: you have to log in to your hosting account by cpanel or FTP client such as Filezilla the .htacces file it is stored in the same folder of worpress instalation sometimes it is hidden and you have to configure the folder o show hidden files

Comment: I'll get in contact with the developer as I'm not sure how to log in to the hosting account.  But, there is a file labeled as .htaccess within the WP file manager plugin, is this the same thing as you mentioned?

Comment: if you backed up your wordpress instalation using a plugin there is a very high chance, but make sure it is the lastest version of the file,  or you can  make a new backup using the same plugin and get the lastest version. If you are not familiar with programing it is better to contact or hire a developer, here in Stack Overflow you can find some good coders.